# Tkinter how to make more elements show up after a button press

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that graphs price history from the steam market
I would like to add 3 different modes "prices" "quantity" "prices vs quantity"
however they all require different parameters to be filled out before they can be graphed
my idea was to create a radio menu that has the different modes and based on which one the user selects the input fields would change to the parameters the different modes require
But I can not find or figure out  a way to do this , please help

Comment: let me elaborate a little bit , to make a button do something , you need a function that you define before you make a button widget so i put in this function to add the other elements and when i clicked the button nothing happened , the screen stayed exactly the same and did nothing else , I tried adding the window and mainloop commands to the function as well and it still did nothing

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I can use the notebook feature to eliminate the need of ever having to create more elements on a button press